# Angular Material Select shows the function name in the option field

Tags: angular, typescript, enums, angular-material

I'm creating a dropdown in my form which takes data from an enum I have created.
So what is happening is when I'm iterating the element in mat-option it list all the fields of the enum as well as the function also which I'm using to call the enum values. This is my enum for language

```
export enum LanguageEnum{
da = "da-DA",
de = "de-DA",
en= "en-EN",
es= "es-ES",
fi= "fi-FI",
fr = "fr-FR",
it= "it-IT",
ko= "ko-KO",
ms= "ms-MS",
nl= "nl-NL",
no= "no-NO",
pl= "pl-PL",
pt= "pt-PT",
sv= "sv-SE"
}
```

Below is the method I'm using to take only values from the enum

```
export namespace LanguageEnum {

        export function getLangCodes() {
          return Object.values(LanguageEnum).filter(
            (langCode) => isNaN(<any>langCode) && langCode !== 'values'
          );
        }
      }
```

and this is how I'm iterating for every enum in my mat-select

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
          <mat-label>Chosen Language</mat-label>
          <mat-select placeholder="Chosen Language" formControlName="ChosenLanguage">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let chosenlang of langCodes.getLangCodes();" [value]="chosenlang">
              {{ chosenlang }}</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Also in ts file I have imported the LanguageEnum 
and initialized

```
this.langCodes = LanguageEnum;
```

[image]

see above output image which shows the function name as well along with the enum entries. 
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
export namespace LanguageEnum {

        function getLangCodes() {
          return Object.values(LanguageEnum).filter(
            (langCode) => isNaN(<any>langCode) && langCode !== 'values'
          );
        }
      }
```

Comment: basically you are saying that I should omit the export in function getLangCodes() right? but this doesn't help it gives error stating 

TypeError: _co.langCodes.getLangCodes is not a function
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]